# Looking for a screen monitoring program for a high school computer lab

Tags: lubuntu, mint, education

As the title says, I'm looking for a screen monitoring program for a high school computer lab that works with either Mint 14 or Lubuntu 12.04. I can't seem to find anything in the software repositories and everything I find through internet searches is a paid program. Does anyone have suggestions on a free and accessible program that I could use?

Comment: Have you looked at **Remmina remote desktop** and the built-in desktop sharing (VNC) client? If I remember correctly,the default Ubuntu has an option to share desktop with or without the ability to click on anything. The client side can also be setup to show no notification or require any password when the desktop is viewed. This is about Ubuntu, don't know about Mint, or Lubuntu.

Comment: let them have some privacy....

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you want to view students screens, that's built into Ubuntu desktop by default. It's called "Desktop Sharing" and you'll find it in the dash. Once it's running, you can connect to it using Remmina, which is also installed by default. It should automatically list available desktops in your network.

I'm not sure if it's installed by default on Lubuntu, but it's in the archives and should work just as good. Linux Mint, of course, is off-topic for this site.

It's provided by the vino package and the dialog to configure it is called vino-preferences.